# passing a dynamic v-model as function param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am very new to vuejs, and I am working with making a dynamic table where the left column will have a hidden input that will ultimately query a database and display the result in a pop up (for a quick cross referencing ability).  I have made it to the point where it builds the table properly with a v-for, but I can't quite figure out how to bind the dynamic v-models to the js function that will run the process.  If I am going about this the completely wrong way, please let me know. Cheers and thanks!

```
...
<tr v-for="tableRow in rtnUnsubs">
  <td class="unsubCell">
  <input name= "[tableRow.share_id]" v-model="[tableRow.share_id]" value="[tableRow.share_id]">{{ tableRow.share_id }}
  <button v-on:click="getSub">view</button>
  </td>
  <td class="unsubCell">{{ tableRow.unsubscriber_type }}</td>
  <td class="unsubCell">{{ tableRow.unsubscriber_id }}</td>
</tr>
...
<script>
...
getSub(/*v-model from input*/) {
            window.alert(/*do some stuff with v-model*/)
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, [the method bound to a `click`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) will get the event, but you can pass whatever you want it to get (include `$event` if you want to add that to other arguments).

When you say you want to "bind v-models", I take it to mean you want to pass the current data.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [{
        share_id: 'IT ME'
      },
      {
        share_id: 'THE OTHER ONE'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    getSub(data) {
      console.log("Working with", data);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="tableRow in rows">
    <input name="tableRow.share_id" v-model="tableRow.share_id" value="tableRow.share_id">{{ tableRow.share_id }}
    <button v-on:click="getSub(tableRow.share_id)">view</button>
  </div>
</div>
```