# Pass dynamic variable to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an `Addresses` component.

```html
...
<div class="mb-2">
  <label class="block mb-1 font-bold">
    Tên <span class="text-red">*</span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First name"
    v-model="type.first_name"
    class="w-full p-2 bg-white border border-gray-300 text-base rounded">
</div>
...
```

I use that component for billing address and shipping address. I pass a prop `type` to specify which one is billing address or shipping address.

```html
<addresses type="billing" :errors="errors"></addresses>
....
<addresses type="shipping" v-show="isDifferentAddress" :errors="errors"></addresses>
```

The problem is how can I pass that `type` prop into v-model to get data for address and shipping separately, then I can put that data into `axios.post`.

Comment: Have you tried passing your prop name i.e type in v-model.Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764293/passing-a-dynamic-v-model-as-function-param

Comment: What are you doing with that `type` prop? Within your component, what is `type.first_name` meant to bind to? Since `type` is a string, it doesn't make sense to bind to its `first_name` property. Also, you should not be using two-way binding (ie `v-model`) on prop values

Comment: @Phil As I said above, I need to get data from 2 instance components (billing and shipping), the type prop will specify which one is billing or shipping.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions. Does your component have a `type` prop? If so, what does it expect the value to be?

Comment: @Phil yes, it has. Its value can be `shipping` or `billing`

Comment: So then why are you binding your input fields to `type.first_name` if `type` is a string?

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't work. That is a bug